# Dynamic Reply-To In Sprout Forms Notification

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Is it possible to get Sprout Forms built in notifications to have dynamic reply to details? Or even from name etc?

I'm wanting my client to be able to respond directly to the client when Sprout Forms notifies them that a new submission has been posted.

Putting {{ formFieldName }} with the relevant field name in the "Reply To Email Address" field made the email not send (so obviously doesn't work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to update your dynamic values. Sprout Forms supports two types of syntax for dynamic information.

1) Shorthand syntax:

```
{formFieldHandle}
```

2) Object syntax:

```
{{ object.formFieldHandle }}
```

Submitted values from your form entry should be available in all of your notification fields:

- Email Recipients
- Subject
- Sender Name
- Sender Email Address (although you probably don't want to set this dynamically as it can affect deliverability)
- Reply To Email Address